# Got `Cannot find entry file` error when bundle android application in Linux

Tags: android, react-native

I use below command to bundle react-native app for android.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file ./index.android.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

but got below error:

```
[07/02/2017 12:35:15] <START> Initializing Packager
[07/02/2017 12:35:15] <START> Building Haste Map
[07/02/2017 12:35:15] <END>   Building Haste Map (14ms)
[07/02/2017 12:35:15] <END>   Initializing Packager (126ms)
[07/02/2017 12:35:15] <START> Transforming files

Cannot find entry file ./index.android.js in any of the roots: ["/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/node_modules/.0.40.0@react-native"]
```

The entry file specified in the command line does exist in my current directory. And some people say this may be caused by `8081` port number is listening. But my 8081 process can't be killed for some reason and whether there is another way to change the port number used by react-native?